# Make magento 3rd item from cart free

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, store

I need to know if there is a way to create this in Magento:
First of all, all my products price are fixed: 9.99$.

So i want to do this: if the client bought three products, the third is free, so it pays 2 products. He can do this as many times as they want, so if you buy 6 products, there will be 2 product free, if he buys 9 products, 3 are free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magneto supports buy x get y free promotions. Information about setting them up is available at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-setup-buy-x-get-y-free

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do this using magento Shoping Cart Price rules.

1. Create a Shoping cart price rule by going to your admin panel and clicking on **Promotions -> Shoping Cart Price rules**.
2. Create a condition for your rule. There is a nice GUI to define the conditions so they will look like: `If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true`
3. Define an Action, actions describe how prices are updated when the conditions of the rule are met. In your case there is an specific action called: **Buy X get Y Free**, which defines a quantity that the customer must purchase to receive a quantity for free. (The Discount Amount is Y.)
4. Complete the labels: lables appears on the order below the subtotal to identify the discount. You can enter a default label for all store views, or enter a different label for each view.
5. Apply the rule. Make sure you save and enable the rule, also you can define a time range when the rule is valid and number of usages.

**For more details check here:** 
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html